# Reorder Stata variable with respect to another variable

Tags: variables, stata

I have these data:

```
Node    Time    Reorder Node
201    8:00:00  395
395    8:10:00  405
280    7:50:00  280
405    8:30:00  201
```

I need to copy the vector called "Time" and reorder it so that the relationship between node number and time in the first two columns is preserved.  In other words, I want to end up with this:

```
Node    Time    Reorder Node    Reorder time
201      8:00:00    395         8:10:00
395      8:10:00    405         8:30:00
280      7:50:00    280         7:50:00
405      8:30:00    201         8:00:00
```

Is this possible in Stata?  I have been looking at `sort , stable` and `bysort` but they don't seem to be right for this.

Thanks!

I

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `merge` solution. I put your toy dataset in `ds1.dta`.

```
. use ds1, clear

. list 

       +------------------------+
       | node      time   node2 |
       |------------------------|
    1. |  201   8:00:00     395 |
    2. |  395   8:10:00     405 |
    3. |  280   7:50:00     280 |
    4. |  405   8:30:00     201 |
       +------------------------+

 . rename (node node2 time) (node2 node time2) 

 . merge 1:m node using ds1

     Result                           # of obs.
    -----------------------------------------
    not matched                             0
    matched                                 4  (_merge==3)
    -----------------------------------------

  . list 

      +------------------------------------------------+
      | node2     time2   node      time        _merge |
      |------------------------------------------------|
   1. |   405   8:30:00    201   8:00:00   matched (3) |
   2. |   280   7:50:00    280   7:50:00   matched (3) |
   3. |   201   8:00:00    395   8:10:00   matched (3) |
   4. |   395   8:10:00    405   8:30:00   matched (3) |
      +------------------------------------------------+
```

`rename` syntax assumes Stata 12. In Stata 11 or older, use individual `rename`s or `renvars` (Stata Journal).

Answer (score 1):

There will be a clever way based on a `merge` of a version of this dataset with itself that someone should be pleased to show you.

I am going to show you a very pedestrian method which has perhaps one advantage, that it is fairly transparent to follow.

I assume that your variables are called `node`, `time` and `node2` and that your `time` is a string variable.

First we put the observation number in a variable:

```
gen long obs = _n
```

Then we initialise a new time variable. If `time` is numeric, the initialisation should be to numeric missing instead:

```
gen time2 = ""
```

Now we loop over observations. For each observation we find out which observation number contains data for the new node number and then we use the value of `time` for that observation.

```
quietly forval i = 1/`=_N' { 
    su obs if node == node2[`i'], meanonly 
    replace time2 = time[r(min)] in `i' 
}
```

`r(min)` is left in memory after `summarize`: it is the minimum value, which will be the value we want if each node occurs precisely once in the data. `r(max)` or even `r(mean)` would work just as well. `=_N' evaluates the number of observations in the dataset on the fly.

Comment: Thanks Nick!  In fact the first dataset I describe is the result of a merge, so it occurred to me to do a second merge based on the variable I called "reorder node."  Each node occurs many times in the data so two merges may be the best way.

Comment: So long as times are constant for multiple observations of each node, the above method should work fine. Just do use `r(min)` or `r(max)`; don't use `r(mean)` which could be a non-integer and/or not correspond to an appropriate observation. Thus if a node occurs in observations 42 and 44, the mean 43 will not be the observation to use, but 42 or 44 will be fine.